# Android ADmob in listview refreshing each time it reappears. I don't want it to get refresh

Tags: android, android-listview, admob

I am using Admob 300X250 Ad in a listview.   I scroll down and scroll up, that Ad reappears, it is showing me a different ad. I don't want that Ad to get changed. It should show me the same ad unless Admob is refreshing that ad according to Admob rules.

May I know what I can do to achieve that?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Put the code that loads the app somewhere other than getView()

Comment: Good Suggestion. But where I can put it besides getView in ArrayAdapter?

Comment: Is the listview in an activity or a fragment?

Comment: I think you may load the ad in fragment and pass the ad into adapter

Comment: User - And how are you suggesting Passing that?

Comment: Time- I am waiting for your reply.  I think that suggestion will help

Comment: can you show the code from your fragment and from your activity? this seems weird to me

Answer (score 0):

Put the AdView outside of the ListView, ie either above or below it.

1. Your code will be much simpler
2. Your ad will be visible for longer, so higher CTR (ie more money to you)
3. You don't have to worry about ad reload as the user scrolls (your current problem)